# How to load html content using JSON in cross domain request into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a widget on one server. In widget am using a script and a div.

code of widget.html file is:-

```
               <script type="text/javascript">
              var _new = new Array()

    _new['Server'] = 'my server name';
            var ip = 'http:my server name/directory/';
            (function() {
            var o2 = document.createElement('script');
            o2.type = 'text/javascript';
            o2.async = true;
            o2.src = ip+'link.js';
            var r = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(o2, r);
            })();
            </script>
           <div id="content"></div>
```

In link.js file am calling a file which contain html content(textfields,button etc) .
code of link.js file is:-

```
          jQuery.getJSON("my server url/user.php?&callback=?", function(data)
      {

        $("#content").html(data);

    });
```

code for user.php is:-

```
              <?php
              $html="<html>
             <body>
            <form method='post'>
        <table>       
            <tbody>
    <tr><td><input value='Name:' type='text' ></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input value='Email:' type='text' ></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input value='City:' type='text' ></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input value='Mobile:'type='text' ></td></tr>           
            </tbody>
           </table>
          </form>
          </div>
          </body>
           </html>";
           echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($html).')';
             ?>
```

When i am running widget.html file on same server html content is retrived and displayed on div. But in different server its not working.

Tell me how to load html content in div on cross domain request.

Plz suggest me some advice.

Comment: It depends on how you wrap the HTML content into JSON on the server side. So please show us the code of `user.php`

Comment: I added code of user.php